# How to avoid sharing session in different browser in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, session-cookies

We are using session in our ASP.NET MVC application. Our config setting is as below

```
<sessionState cookieless="true" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" timeout="20"/>
```

It generates url as:

```
http://localhost:34343/(S(ypr1jdz2lk5ysiqearcrbgty))/Dashboard
```

Scenario we want to achieve is: if we login to application in Chrome and open new tab of chrome then user should be logged. This is working fine.

But if user opens up new Chrome window or any other browser's window and tried to access above dashboard url, user should redirect to login page again, which is not happening now.

We believe this is because of the session is shared between all the browsers. 
The application is stable and we don't want to change any config setting for this.

Is there any way or workaround by which we can avoid session sharing in another browser window or another browser?

In-short, we want to achieve same behavior how Gmail works, it asks for login if copy and paste inbox's url in new browser window or in new browser.

Comment: Value `(S(ypr1jdz2lk5ysiqearcrbgty))` in url is a session id?

Comment: The simple thing you want to do is to use session with cookie. With that cookie will have session id. Different cookie is generated for different browsers. That way user will be redirected to login page if user opens url in different browser.

Comment: If you can not avoid session id in url, the other way is to customize the session id generation and session id validation. The session id generation should be customized to include browser identity so that the session id in url becomes invalid with different browser and you can redirect user to login page.

Comment: @Chetan. This sound a concrete solution. Any reference for this about how to generate customize session id and where that code needs to be in MVC application?

Comment: Also any reference about browser identity?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394380/generate-its-own-session-id-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664770/how-to-get-user-browser-name-user-agent-in-asp-net-core